# Beautify Angularjs URL

Tags: angularjs

Normally, my Angularjs URL would look like this:

```
.../index.html#/Menu
```

Now I would love to convert it into

```
.../index.html/#/Menu
```

or even better:

```
.../index/#/Menu
```

I've been searching for it without luck. Can anyone help me with it?

UPDATE: this is an application for mobile devices, so Angularjs would run locally.

Comment: you need to serve the content of the index.html page through an http handler that returns it at /index/

Comment: yeah I know. The problem is that this is an app for mobile, that means Angularjs would run locally.

Comment: What are you using on the phone to provide index.html?  AngularJS always runs locally.

Comment: By running locally, I mean that the app only contact server to get json data. Angularjs and html files will be placed inside the phone to do all the stuff including routing.

Answer (score 0):

`$location.html5Mode` is what you're looking for: [$location docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) (search for html5 mode section)

Comment: actually I want to use the hashbang :D